# get changes in git remote branch

Tags: git, git-clone, git-diff, git-log

I am a tester and have limited knowledge about Git. I have cloned a project to create local repository. When I have to get changes for last 'x' days,
 I run `git pull` followed by `git diff '@{ x days ago}'`.

Now I want to get changes in developers branch. So I have cloned his branch in another repository using `git clone -b dev_branch <url>`. How can I get his diffs for last x days?

Also comment about doing the both tasks in same repository.
Thanks

Comment: Why can't the other developer push their dev branch to origin, and you pull from there?

Comment: This is a release branch

Comment: They could still push that branch do a different name on the remote, like `git push origin developer-release-branch`?

Answer (score 0):

You can clone entire repository at one place.

```
git clone <URL>
```

After Successful clone

```
git branch -a
```

This will list all available branches

Switch to developer branch

```
git checkout <dev_branch_name>
```

Perform Your differences operation.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, for getting changes in master, I'll need to `checkout -f master` and then do difference operation?
Can I freely switch like this and get correct diffs?

Comment: yes, you can simply do git checkout master , (not sure what -f does), to confirm your current branch you can always do git status

Comment: `-f is for forceful checkout`. To perform `git diff` I need to do `git pull`. how can I do that in dev_branch after `git checkout dev_branch`? will that create problem while switching branch?

Comment: No, there is no issue , you can do git pull origin <dev_branch_name> while you are in dev branch

Answer (score 0):

Git supports many different remotes, and depending on your structure, you might be able to use this:

```
git remote add <remotename> <developer-url>
git checkout -b dev-branch <remotename>/dev-branch
```

This allows you to use git in a completely decentralised way. However, it will probably be easier to have a central main repository and have all developers push branches to there, feature branches as well as production-ready code.

If other developers want to push feature branches it would look like this:

```
git checkout -b feature
git push -u origin feature
```

If it's their version of the release branch, I'd argue that it's still a feature branch as you're not ready to put it into release yet, but you can still push to a branch on the remote with a different name, it's just perhaps not the best practice:

```
git checkout release
git push origin HEAD:developername-release-branch
```